# Unable to Display Loading Component in Next.js v13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm having trouble implementing a loading component in Next.js v13. According to the documentation, I created a `loading.tsx` file in my `src` directory, but it's not being displayed. I've also included a function to fetch data. However, every time I refresh the page, it directly shows the API response from the server without displaying the loading component. Could anyone suggest how to rectify this? Additionally, is there any further configuration required to display the loading component?

Here is my code:

In `page.tsx`:

```
import { IResult } from '@/interface';
import Results from '@/components/Results';

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY

export default async function Home({ searchParams } : {searchParams: any}) {
  const genre = searchParams.genre || 'fetchTrending';
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${genre === 'fetchTopRated'
    ? 'movie/top_rated' :
      'trending/all/week'
  }?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`, { next: {revalidate: 100000 }})

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }

  const data = await res.json()

  const results = data.results as IResult[]

  console.log({results})
  return (
    <>
      <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-4">
        <Results results={results}></Results>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

And in `loading.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Loading() {
  return (
    <div>loading...</div>
  )
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Loading` component works when you navigate through pages.

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming)

> An instant loading state is fallback UI that is shown immediately upon
> navigation. You can pre-render loading indicators such as skeletons
> and spinners, or a small but meaningful part of future screens such as
> a cover photo, title, etc. This helps users understand the app is
> responding and provides a better user experience.

if you navigate from a different page to `Home` page, you will see the loading component

Comment: Thank you! I missed the part of "fallback UI that is shown immediately upon navigation". When I navigate to the page on navigation. the loading icon was displayed.

Comment: How does this in any way answer the question?

Comment: @Yeats post owner says `every time I refresh the page, it directly shows the API response from the server without displaying the loading component.`

Answer (score 4):

In NextJS 13, instead of adding **loading.tsx** and **page.tsx** in **src** you are supposed to add these files in **app**, if you are using src then **src/app/...**

For example if you want to create home route then your file structure would look like:
**src/app/home/page.tsx**
**src/app/home/loading.tsx**

You don't need any extra configuration for this

For reference - [Nextjs loading docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, your comment is correct and I actually the had the same directory structure as you described.